# Limitar tamanho de imagem sem que fique cortada

Tags: android, imageview

Como faço pra limitar o tamanho de um *ImageButton* dentro de um *LinearLayout*?

Eu limitei o tamanho do *LinearLayout* e deixei os tamanhos das imagens como `wrap_content` achando que se ajustaria ao tamanho do *layout* mas a imagem ficou cortada. Quando não limito o tamanho do *layout* a imagem fica bem maior do que eu gostaria que ficasse.

**Código:**

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addproduto"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/setacima" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/tiraproduto"
        android:src="@drawable/setabaixo"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que a imagem se ajuste à dimensão do botão, que é determinada, neste caso, pelas dimensões do *LinearLayout*, use o atributo [android:scaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType) com o tipo *centerInside*.
A imagem será apresentada centrada e redimensionada sem perda das proporções.

Na declaração das dimensões da *TextView* deverá usar a unidade **sp** e não **dp**, além que a altura deverá ser declarada como `wrap_content` para evitar que o texto seja cortado em altura.

Julgo que também será necessário adicionar o atributo `android:layout_weight` às imagens, senão as *views* ficarão umas em cima das outras.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/addproduto"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/setacima" 
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="25sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/tiraproduto"
        android:src="@drawable/setabaixo"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

É claro que pode também limitar as dimensões do botão directamente nele e usando o atributo `android:scaleType="centerInside"` para redimensionar a imagem.
Nesse caso as dimensões do *LinarLayout* deverão/poderão ser declaradas com `wrap_content`

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/addproduto"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/setacima" 
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta colocar essa linha na declaração do seu imageView no XML:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Isso vai fazer com que a imagem se auto ajuste no layout.